What AI character chat services automatically fill in descriptions based on a name and short description?
I'm only aware of an app named Summon Worlds. Are there any other suggestions? Instead of providing detailed descriptions, only a short description is provided and other details are automatically filled in by an AI.

Besides Summon Worlds, check also Joyland.AI and AIFreeBox.
I believe Character AI website won't satisfy your needs for brief descriptions. However, I've read that the Character AI apps for mobile (iOS and/or Android) allow users to create characters with minimal input. I haven't tested them though.
Joyland.ai enables users to design unique AI characters with just basic information.
AIFreeBox allows you to enter as much (or as little) information as you want. Check here: https://aifreebox.com/list/ai-character-description-generator
